# PATH_INFO variable is always empty when use fastcgi on MacOS

Tags: macos, nginx, fastcgi

I installed nginx via brew and wrote this simple config for my python app:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen      3000;
 
    location / {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    localhost:8082;
    }
}
```

When I start my app on 8082 and try to make any request, I always get response for main page. I found the reason. Flask gets url for matching from enveron PATH_INFO. And in my case this variable is always empty.

I have this problem only on MacOS. This app works well on Linux with same nginx config. What is my mistake?

Comment: What's in `fastcgi_params` on MacOS and on Linux? PATH_INFO will be set in that file (if at all).

Comment: @RichardSmith you're right, PATH_INFO is missing in fastcgi_params. But I don't understand why. I can't find in any documentation that this variable can be removed.

Comment: It's not included in the FreeBSD version of `fastcgi_params` either. Which makes me think the file has been patched on some Linux distributions.